# Nginx (as reverse proxy) previous request location settings is overcoming another request location setting

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have the following nginx settings:

```
 upstream cluster_web {
         ip_hash;
         server 192.168.115.82 weight=3;
         server 192.168.115.92 weight=2;
         server 192.168.115.100 weight=2;
         server 192.168.115.95 weight=3;
         server 192.168.115.103 weight=1;
}

server {
     location /app1/ {
          proxy_pass http://192.168.115.92;
     }

     location / {
          proxy_pass http://cluster_web;
     }
}
```

The point is, after a user access the / location, he can't achieve the server defined in location rule /app1/, because apparently nginx is using the ip_hash server in the upstream setting from the previous request. Am I missing some setting? Is this correct? By the way, I have two reverse proxy servers, one on the internet and another for the LAN users.

Best regards!

Comment: Why do you believe the problem is here, and not in your other reverse proxy server?

Comment: Hi Michael, both reverse proxies are using similar settings.

Comment: I'm convinced that I've found a bug. I'll try another product.

Answer (score -2):

It wasn't a bug.

I had to use break; after the proxy_pass directives.

Comment: Please edit this to be a proper answer (show us how your config looks like now).